# Installing Multiple Versions Of A Windows Service On The Same PC

Tags: .net-3.5, msbuild, windows-services, installation

I have a .NET 3.5 Windows Service that comes in several different configurations/flavours ie. Release, Test, Debug etc.  I've created an installer package for the service which is built as part of an msbuild script, but I need to be able to build the installers in a way which would allow each flavour of the service to be installed on the same machine.  Does anyone know the best way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/MultipleInstNetWinService.aspx) will be of help?

> **The Problem**
>
> When reviewing the `ServiceInstaller`
>   class using Reflector, you'll see it
>   does a Win32 call to `CreateService` in
>   the `ServiceInstaller.Install` method.
>   `CreateService` will return the
>   `ERROR_DUPLICATE_SERVICE_NAME` return
>   code whenever the method is called
>   with a `serviceName` or `displayName`
>   parameter that matches that of an
>   already installed service. This is
>   what causes the `Win32Exception` to be
>   thrown in the above window and
>   ultimately causes the second install
>   to fail. You can view the complete
>   documentation on the CreateService
>   function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682450.aspx).
>
> To get around this, all that needs to
>   be done is to dynamically set the
>   service name during installation and
>   service startup to a known value and
>   to make sure that value is different
>   for each instance of the service you
>   install.
>
> **The Solution**
>
> All that needs to be done is to make
>   sure that the name of each service
>   installation instance is unique. Then
>   you need to have copies of
>   installation directories for each
>   service instance you'd like to have.
>   Finally, you need to be able to set
>   the service name dynamically during
>   installation and startup. This will be
>   facilitated using the *app.config* file.

The article continues by providing step-by-step instructions on how you can install multiple instances of a .NET Windows Service on the same machine.

Of course, I can't help but wonder *why* exactly you would need to run a Debug and Release version at the same time on the same machine.

Comment: Thanks, that helps.  As for the reasons for needing this... not my idea, quite frankly, I don't think it's necessary. According to our senior dev, we should do it as part of our build, although I'm not entirely sure why!

Comment: @TabbyCool: That's a really weird requirement. Testing the release version of a build is a good idea (just to make sure compiler optimizations don't introduce bugs), but I see no reason why they'd need to run simultaneously. Considering that no end user will be running in that configuration, I'd expect it to just make debugging all that much more difficult. If you need to be able to debug a release build, a better idea is just to generate PDB symbols for the release build rather than trying to run both. Anyway, glad to help.

Comment: I think it's in case we ever need to run the UAT environment on the same server as the live system - we had to move our live database onto the same server as UAT recently due to server problems.  Not ideal, but the budget has been cut and we don't exactly have a lot of servers going spare!

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to draw attention to the comments in the article Cody gray references.  It seems that the author and a commenter agreed that there was an easier method using sc.exe as follows

```
sc \\myserver create NewService binpath= c:\nt\system32\NewServ.exe
```

Comment: sc create NewService binpath="pathtoservice.exe" worked for us. Thank you.